# Heroku: "Process exited with status 127" after deploying ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake

After deploying some changes to Heroku, I am getting the following error (even if I revert the changes).

```
» heroku web.1 - - Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 59617 -e production`
» app web.1 - - /usr/bin/env: ruby : No such file or directory
» heroku web.1 - - Process exited with status 127
» heroku web.1 - - State changed from starting to crashed
```

Seems that my app does not understand ruby anymore. These are my files in /bin:

**bundle**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
load Gem.bin_path('bundler', 'bundle')
```

**rails**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

**rake**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rake'
Rake.application.run
```

**heroku run "gem env"**

[image: heroku run "gem env"]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some hours trying different solutions, this is the only thing that worked for me:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

And push the changes again to Heroku.

Comment: I moved from developing on windows to mac and I had this same problem, among others. This fixed this particular problem and everything is running fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Do you happen to have a solution for a Django app?